# Generate 2D array with adjacent elements not being x+1

Tags: arrays, matrix

I need to develop an algorithm which would accept two numbers `m` and `n` - dimensions of 2D array - as input and generate 2D array filled with numbers `[1..m*n]` with the following condition:

All (4) elements adjacent to a given element cannot be equal to `currentElement + 1`

*Adjacent elements are located to the two/three/four sides (depending on position) of a given element*

```
0 1 0
1 2 1
0 1 0
```

*(E.g four 1s are adjacent to 2)*

**Example:**

*Input:* m = 3, n = 3 (does not essentially have to be square matrix)

*(Sample) output:*

```
[
[7, 2, 5],
[1, 6, 9],
[3, 8, 4]
]
```

Note that there apparently may exist more than one possible output. In that case, numbers in the array have to be generated **randomly** (though still meeting the conditions), not following any preset sequence (e.g not `[ [1, 3, 5], [4, 6, 2], [7, 9, 8] ]` because it clearly uses a non-randomly generated sequence of numbers, odds first, then evens, etc)

Basically, for the same input, on two different occasions, two different arrays should be generated.

P.S: that was a coding interview question and I wonder how I could solve it, so, any help is highly appreciated.